# ReportViewer and DataTable as a data source

Tags: c#, datatable, reportviewer

I have a `ReportViewer` with `DataTable` as a data source. the report doesn't show any data. 
Should I add a `DataSet` and put an empty `DataTable` similar in structure to the one which will be loaded from DB?

note: the `metroGrid` show data, unlike the report.

```
DataTable dt=com1("select * from tblPerson");
dt.TableName = "DataTable1";
metroGrid1.DataSource = dt;
reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
ReportDataSource source = new ReportDataSource("DataTable1", dt);
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(source);
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: What's the name of the expected datasource inside the associated RDLC?

Comment: I add a dataset & add to it a datatable name it DataTable1.

Comment: Check if your RDL file has an association with the Data source you created with name DataTable1. Also i think there are lot of question already asked check it first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360992/binding-a-datasource-to-a-rdl-in-report-server-programmatically-ssrs